# synchronized(this) block within the synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized-block

The following is the code snippet from **java concurrency in practice** book while discussing **open calls**. The point I'm not getting is that the way setLocation method is declared, it is already synchronized and again calling the synchronized(this) block within the same method, why this ? Is it type mistake ? The synchronized method already holds the lock on this method then why again for the same object ?

```
   @ThreadSafe 
    class Taxi { 
        @GuardedBy("this") private Point location, destination; 
        private final Dispatcher dispatcher; 
        ... 
        public synchronized Point getLocation() { 
            return location; 
        } 
        public synchronized void setLocation(Point location) { 
            boolean reachedDestination; 
            synchronized  (this) { 
                this.location = location; 
                reachedDestination = location.equals(destination); 
            } 
            if (reachedDestination) 
                dispatcher.notifyAvailable(this); 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an error in the book. See [the errata](http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/errata.html)

> In Listing 10.6, Taxi.setLocation should not be a synchronized method. (The synchronized block in its body is correct, however.)

Comment: Thanks Nizet breaking my head thinking that some hidden meaning for such declaration, didn't thought about errata.